# Loopback polymorphic relation based on property

Tags: loopbackjs

I have review the loopback polymorphic relation docs (https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Polymorphic-relations.html) and I am trying to determine if I can achieve a polymorphic relation that suits the following needs:

I have List, Task, and Event models. Lists can have many Tasks OR have many Events. Lists also have a `type` property that defines what kind of child objects it has. ie, `"tasks"`, `"events"`. What I'd like is to have a polymorphic "items" relation on the List model that would query whichever relation is defined by the `type` property. So if I queried a List with type `"events"` with `{include: "items"}` it would return Events in the items array.

Is this implementation supported by Loopback?

Comment: did u manage to do it?